# How do you start software installed with flatpak?

Tags: software-installation, kde, flatpak

Hope, I'm on the right site for this question.

So I tried to install **KRuler** with flatpak doing `flatpak install org.kde.kruler` and then tried to run it with `flatpak run --user org.kde.kruler` which gives me

```
error: app/org.kde.kruler/x86_64/stable not installed
```

---

**What I did trying to debug:**

Running `flatpak list` yields

```
Name               Application ID              Version Branch      Installation
...
Adwaita theme      org.kde.KStyle.Adwaita              5.15-21.08  system
KDE Application P… org.kde.Platform                    5.15-21.08  system
KRuler             org.kde.kruler              22.12.2 stable      system
...
```

and trying `flatpak install org.kde.kruler` again (selecting `1`) fails too:

```
Looking for matches…
Remotes found with refs similar to ‘org.kde.kruler’:

   1) ‘flathub’ (system)
   2) ‘flathub’ (user)

Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-2]: 1
Skipping: org.kde.kruler/x86_64/stable is already installed
```

I think that option 2 above is because I did

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

---

I already removed and reinstalled and don't know how to continue. How can I find an approach to solve this? If it matters, I'm running **Linux Lite 6.0**, which is based on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `flatpak install org.kde.kruler`, you have to select `2` to install it for your user.

```
Looking for matches…
Remotes found with refs similar to ‘org.kde.kruler’:

   1) ‘flathub’ (system)
   2) ‘flathub’ (user)

Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-2]: 2

org.kde.kruler permissions:
    ipc       fallback-x11         wayland              x11
    dri       file access [1]      dbus access [2]

    [1] xdg-config/kdeglobals:ro
    [2] com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar, org.kde.KGlobalSettings,
        org.kde.kconfig.notify


        ID                       Branch    Op    Remote    Download
 1. [✓] org.kde.kruler.Locale    stable    i     flathub     6,6 kB / 110,1 kB
 2. [✓] org.kde.kruler           stable    i     flathub   264,2 kB / 305,9 kB

Installation complete.
```

Then `flatpak run --user org.kde.kruler` works as expected:

```
Gtk-Message: 10:13:56.607: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
```

(The log messages are [harmless](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263690).)